# Set the user accounts in Task Scheduler through C#

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I am trying to set the following options in Task Scheduler using my C# program.

```
1. In settings tab of Task scheduler, check the box "If the task fails, restart every 1 minute"
2. In General tab of Task scheduler, under security options, set it to "BigDataService" for "When running the task, use the following user account" and provide its password.
```

My current code looks like this:

```
 using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
 {
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger();
    var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(section1["ScheduledTime"]);
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + startTime;
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;
    td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
    trigger.Id = "Data";
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"DataUpload.exe", argument, null));
    var foldername = ts.GetFolder(@"\Bigdata");
    Console.WriteLine(foldername.Path);
    foldername.RegisterTaskDefinition(section1["JobName"], td);
}
```

New Cod (works fine with RegisterTaskDefinition, but when I add the RepetitionInterval line, the task does not get created in the BigData folder.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
 {
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger();
    var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(section1["ScheduledTime"]);
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + startTime;
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;
    td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
    trigger.Id = "Data";
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"DataUpload.exe", argument, null));
    var foldername = ts.GetFolder(@"\Bigdata");
    Console.WriteLine(foldername.Path);   
    foldername.RegisterTaskDefinition(section1["JobName"], td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate,"Bigdataservice", "password");
}
```

Comment: What is your question though?  Is the code not working?

Comment: @xDaevax: This is my current code. I am not sure what should I add to my current code for the two settings.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383480(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @xDaevax: I went through this link. But not sure which is the correct property for setting the two settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set restart Interval to 1 minute:

```
td.Settings.RestartInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

To set the login:

```
td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.Group;
// Pass the credentials when you register the task
foldername.RegisterTaskDefinition(section1["JobName"], td,
    TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, "DOMAIN\\USERNAME", "Pas$w0rD");
```

Comment: RegisterTaskDefinition works fine. When I add the RestartInterval, the task does not get created in the appropriate folder.  I have added the new code in the question.

Comment: Try removing the slash from the foldername